# python list comprehension with function call on if and on return

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class Campaign which has a method `def get_num_matches(self, search_terms_list)` and a variable `campaigns` that contains a list of instances of this class.

Then I have the following code:

`selected_campaigns = [(c.get_num_matches(search_terms_list), c.bid_price, c.name, c) for c in campaigns if c.get_num_matches(search_terms_list) > 0]`

Realize that get_num_matches is called twice to mount the list comprehension. 
How to make it be called just one time, but keep using a single list comprehension?

Comment: Wow, 10 answers .... that's a lot to sort through. The accepted memoization answer isn't a good match here (or anywhere?!) since there isn't a hashable value. But the internal generator works. Try `selected_campaigns = [(num_matches, c.bid_price, c.name, c) for num_matches,c in ((c.get_num_matches(search_terms_list), c) for c in campaigns) if num_matches]`.

Comment: I just did that now, that was what I was looking for, thanks!